# How to get conditional row element in cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, cypress

I am testing my application with cypress. For example I have 4 Values in my Table.

I want to get a row having on specific value in this case cypress-farm, and then I want to get the id column of that row which has cypress-farm, but cypress takes every id column inside my table. Can someone show me a pointer how to do it? What do I miss
**The value "selector" in this case is the id column** the part where my question is the lines above **cy.request**

```
public static addproductToFarm(selector:string, productName:string) {
        cy.get(".list").then(($temp1) =>{
            cy.get(".list")
                .contains("cypress-farm")
                .get(selector).then(($temp)=>{
                const txt = $temp.text()

                cy.request({
                    url: Cypress.env("api_server") + "products/",
                    method: 'POST',
                    form: false,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    },
                    body: {
                        availability: true,
                        category: {
                            hasOthers: false,
                            id: 1,
                            indexRanking: 0,
                            name: "Obst",
                            shown: true,
                            subCategories: [
                                null
                            ]
                        },
                        delivery: true,
                        description: productName,
                        descriptionExcerpt: "Cypress Product",
                        farmId: txt,
                        name: "Apple by Postman",
                        pickUp: true,
                        price: 10.00,
                        quantity: 10,
                        storageLimit: 10,
                        unit: "kg",
                        visibility: true
                    }


                })

            })
        } )

        return this;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want `.find(selector)` instead of `.get(selector)`.

`get()` starts from the document, but `find()` starts from the previous subject (the result of `.contains("cypress-farm")`).

See [Get vs Find](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Get-vs-Find)

> The cy.get command always starts its search from the `cy.root` element. In most cases, it is the document element, unless used inside the `.within()` command. The `.find` command starts its search from the current subject.

Comment: Hi I tried it but it does not work, the reason is my contains is just one column maybe thats why? the .list is my complete table but still it does not work

Comment: It's easier if you take a look at the HTML, but when you talk about rows and columns you might have table elements (<tr> for row and <td> for columns). If so, `.contains("cypress-farm")` will yield the closest element to that text, in this case a <td>, but you probably want the <tr> instead - which would be `.contains("tr", "cypress-farm")`.

Comment: Or if there are for example <div role="row"> for the row, then substitute `.contains("div[role='row']", "cypress-farm")` to target the row element.

Comment: Hi I followed your advice and found item.row and changed my get inside my then to this: cy.get(".item.row")